# iOS animate a blur for a view

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, blur, core-image

I would like to quickly animate a blur on a UIView to use as a transition in my app. I'm having trouble knowing where to start. I believe core image is the proper tool for the job. Can anyone point me to a sample of how to blur a UIView? I'm assuming I will need to convert the view into a single UIImage, but I don't know where to proceed from there.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://www.iphonedevwiki.net/index.php?title=CAFilter try it using your UIView but since CIGaussianBlur isn't present on iOS as of 5.1, you may need to find a different way of accomplishing this on 5.x and older.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

rasterizeScale of a uiview's layer is what you need, Here is the code for adding blur effect to UIVIew:

```
CALayer *layer = [self.blurView layer];
[layer setRasterizationScale:0.3];
[layer setShouldRasterize:YES];
```

For details refer to [Apple Documentation of CALayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html), Also this [tutorial](http://www.dimzzy.com/blog/2010/11/blur-effect-for-uiview/) might help You, hope that helps

Comment: That is as ugly as can be... I was hoping for something cleaner. I assume I can just animate the rasterizationScale property?

Answer (score 9):

Taking a snapshot of the View and using GPUImage from Brad Larson (the GPUImageGaussianBlurFilter) got me some nice results.

To animate the view I created a ImageView with the blurred image and animated the alpha channel from 0 to 1 to make the blur appear progressively.

Alternatively, I presume its possible to increase the blursize per frame.

```
#import "GPUImage.h"
...
[view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
...
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
...
GPUImageGaussianBlurFilter * filter = [[GPUImageGaussianBlurFilter alloc] init];
filter.blurSize = 0.5;
UIImage * blurred = [filter imageByFilteringImage:image];
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it works great, but now the GPUImage framework has changed, and the property blurSize has been removed. I try to use  the new property : `filter.blurRadiusInPixels = 50;` but the blur effect is not enough strong on my snapshot, have you an idea for that ? If I try to add a value superior to 200 my app is crashing..

Answer (score 3):

I recently did some tests with blurring a series of images at different blur settings and animating them simply with UIImageView. You might want to take a look:

[AnimatedGaussianBlur](https://github.com/kenshin03/AnimatedGaussianBlur)